# show multiple point in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi i'm using google api for showing multiple points on map, but it is showing `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object`

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
         var map;
              var geocoder;
              var centerChangedLast;
              var reverseGeocodedLast;
              var currentReverseGeocodeResponse;

              function initialize() {
                  var myOptions = {
                            zoom: 40,
                            center: (10.566057,76.235787),   // set some default latlng here, e.g $data[0]['lat'], $data[0]['lng']
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'getDataForMap',
                            type : 'POST',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            beforeSend : function() {

                            },
                            complete : function() {

                            },
                            success : function(responseData) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < responseData.legth; i++) {
                                     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(responseData[i].latitude+','+responseData[i].longitude);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: (10.566057,76.235787),
                                        map: map,
                                        title: responseData[i].name
                                    });
                            }

                            }
                        });
              } 


    <div id="map" style="width:200px; height:200px">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
                <div id="crosshair"></div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="initialize();">Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `google.maps.LatLng` or `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`: `(10.566057,76.235787)`

A `google.maps.LatLng`: `center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.566057,76.235787)`

A `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`: `center: {lat: 10.566057, lng:76.235787}`

**LatLng**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.566057, 76.235787),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**LatLngLiteral**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: 10.566057, lng: 76.235787},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: does the new dynamic lat and log from server side will show on button click.